# How to make hex vals acceptable to the compiler?

Tags: c#, enums, flags, winmm, enum-flags

I'm trying to use the code at http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/playsound.html

It causes several err msgs, though, namely: "Unexpected character '×'" 26 times.

So, I tried changing the vals to verbatim strings, like so:

SND_SYNC = @"0×0000",

...but now I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

I realize that I can convert those strings to ints, but is that really the way to do it? I'm afraid I might be able to get it to compile that way, but that it still won't work (or worse). What is the appropriate way to mark these hex vals as such, so that the compiler accepts them?

Here's the first bit of the code:

[DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool PlaySound(string pszSound, UIntPtr hmod, uint fdwSound);

```
[Flags]
public enum SoundFlags
{
    SND_SYNC = 0×0000, // <- "unexpected char 'x'"
```

Comment: I must be missing something. Why don't you replace all **`x`** s with **`X`** (they are different chars) in VS editor.

Comment: Are you saying the x's should be uppercased? If not, can you give an example of just what you mean?

Comment: When I copy and paste the code from the sample code in the link to my Visual Studio environment I get no errors.  You sure there is not some other problem somewhere above this code that might be causing all these problems?

Comment: No I say they are not `X`(88 or 120). Their codes are 215. try this code `var x1 = (int)'×'; var x2 = (int)'x';`

Comment: Yep, that did it - changing the lowercase x's to uppercase x's solved the problem - and the code works a treat/like a charm! Why the confusion and inconsistency, I don't know, but I'm glad it works now with such a simple fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, at least, I had to change all of the lowercase x's to uppercase X's to get it to work.

Comment: In fact, what you did is not changing to uppercase, see the `U+00D7` char [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) You replaced all these multiplication signs with X

Comment: That's too metaphysical for my tastes - I simply replaced those little x's with bigger X's - I know, I was there! ;-)
And it works, and that's all I really care about.

Comment: I am glad that you are happy. I only wanted to say, you have no idea what you have replaced :)

Comment: The question still remains as to why that code works for some people, but won't compile for others.

Comment: Clay, although you linked [this page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/playsound.html) in your question, you seem to have copied the code from [here](http://codinglifestyle.wordpress.com/2010/04/30/playsound-a-better-way-to-play-wav-files-in-c/) (or a similar site). Take a closer look at this char `×`. It is not letter `x`. I really don't see what is so hard to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign them - SND_SYNC = 0x000

Comment: That's what the original code does, but it doesn't compile. I'll add the first bit of code to my original post, so you can see exactly what the code is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
int val = 0x12fe;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with some code I copied from a website, into a c# Visual Studio 2012 editor, and the x's it pasted were not x's at all but some other character.  Replacing them with an actual x character, uppercase or lowercase worked for me.